# How to align my list inside my list-group-items to print pretty

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, django-bootstrap4

I am printing some `list-group-items` inside a card container like below it is not aligned properly. I'm using Bootstrap 4. My goal is to align all 3 fields in a neat tabbed column. Also open to other suggestions.

I used a `|` symbol as a separator. This is my code for what I have already done.

```
<!--HTML-->
<body>

<div class="containers">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header py-2">Testcases</div>
          <div id="rightContainer" class="list-group" style="height:425px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <!--Populated by JS function -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And the script to populate the above card container is written below. (Why is it populated like this? Because some selection needs to happen, which I require to send to the backend via AJAX, for which the response calls a success function which calls the `populate_rightcontainer()`) :

```
<!--SCRIPT-->

<script>
  function populate_rightcontainer(response) {
    $("#rightContainer > a").removeClass("active");
    $("#rightContainer > a").hide();
    $("#rightContainer").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      var str = response[i].replace(/\s+/g, "");
      var arr = str.split("|");
      var testcase = arr[0] + "  |  " + arr[1] + "  |  " + arr[2];
      if (arr[2] == "Passed") {
        $("#rightContainer").append('<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0">' + testcase + "</a>");
      }
      if (arr[2] == "Failed") {
        $("#rightContainer").append('<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger py-0">' + testcase + "</a>");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And it currently looks like this which is not pretty:
[image: container of list-group-items]

Can you help/suggest/modify my container align columns pretty?

Here is Plnkr of my code to play with:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EumtRHhzNb4nEFhScWjY?p=preview

P.S: Bonus fix would be when I tried to split by `|`, it didn't work unless I replaced/removed space, I messed up my timestamp as you can see in above picture. I don't know how to fix that now.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @K.C. , I wanted the 3 columns to have set size regardless of the length of the text. Sometimes, the name portion can be long which will mess up the table. Similar to how it is in my Plnkr sample I have linked above. Also, I am open to suggestions. My users don't like the dividers I have used, and also wanted a better look/presentation of that container.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't even close to possible in CSS alone, it needs to be done in HTML. Why not rebuild it as an ACTUAL table?

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>
      <a href="#">arr[0]</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">arr[1]</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">arr[2]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Here you go: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/xDIdHnC5tU5lGYPg?p=preview

HTML:

```
<table id="rightContainer" style="height:225px; overflow-y: scroll">
```

JS:

```
  function populate_rightcontainer(myJSON){
    $("#rightContainer").empty();   
    var data = myJSON.data;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var str = data[i].replace(/\s+/g,'');
        var arr = str.split('|');
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        var elementOne = $('<td>' +arr[0] + '</td>');
        var elementTwo = $('<td>' +arr[1] + '</td>');
        var elementThree = $('<td>' +arr[2] + '</td>');
        row.append(elementOne);
        row.append(elementTwo);
        row.append(elementThree);
        $("#rightContainer").append(row);               
        if(arr[2] == "Passed"){
            row.addClass('list-group-item-success');
        }
        if(arr[2] == "Failed"){ 
            row.addClass('list-group-item-danger');
        }
    }
  }
```